# MongoDB not connecting while using host option?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, atlas

I am unable to connect Atlas MongoDB while using `--host` option, But i'm able to connect while using `--uri` option where did i made a mistake?

For example:

--uri option It's working fine

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<dbname>" --gzip --out=/dir1/dir2
```

--host option getting error like

> Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

```
mongodump --host <hostname>:<port> --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase <dbusername> --gzip --db <dbname> --out /dir/dir2
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting using mongosh (mongo shell) using the same connection string?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you have to use connectionString in URI format.

Comment: @Yahya I am able to login using mongosh here is the command `mongosh "mongodb+srv://<hostname>/<dbname>" --username <username>`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i have used the below command but it's taking all the database dump 

`mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<dbname>" --gzip --out=/home/dir1/`

But i want specific database dump only. How can i get this done, Please guide me.

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here, if you connect using `--uri` you use a MongoDB URI resource (starting with `mongodb://`)

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017" [additional options]
```

But if you use `--host` you don't, as this is not a MongoDB URI:

```
mongodump --host="mongodb0.example.com:27017"  [additional options]
```

Source: [mongodump docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/)

Comment: Without URI option we can able to take dump is possible? Shall i use only host option?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment you can try this:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/" --db=<dbname> --gzip --out=/home/dir1/
```

You may need to specify the authentication database:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/?authSource=admin" --db=<dbname> --gzip --out=/home/dir1/
```

See [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I just started exploring MongoDB, Can you please give me command using --host option with no --URI option.

Comment: How many times do you like me to repeat? You cannot use `mongodb+srv` with `--host` option - period.